# What MySQL ini/cnf setting is used to control the MySQL query cache memory allocation?

Tags: mysql

What MySQL ini/cnf setting is used to control the MySQL query cache memory allocation

Answer (score 1):

> To set the size of the query cache, set the *query_cache_size* system variable. Setting it to 0 disables the query cache. The default size is 0, so the query cache is disabled by default. To reduce overhead significantly, also start the server with *query_cache_type*=0 if you will not be using the query cache.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-cache-configuration.html and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_query_cache_size